# How to prevent filename expansion in for loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, wildcard, expansion

In a for loop like this,

```
for i in `cat *.input`; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

if one of the input file contains entries like `*a`, it will, and give
the filenames ending in 'a'.

Is there a simple way of preventing this filename expansion?

Because of use of multiple files, globbing (`set -o noglob`) is not a
good option. I should also be able to filter the output of `cat` to
escape special characters, but

```
for i in `cat *.input | sed 's/*/\\*'`
    ...
```

still causes `*a` to expand, while

```
for i in `cat *.input | sed 's/*/\\\\*'`
    ...
```

gives me `\*a` (including backslash). [ I guess this is a different
question though ]

Comment: Do you want to do something with each line or with each word in the input files? Because if one of the input files contains e.g. foo bar.txt then the for loop would do one iteration with i set to foo, and one with i set to bar.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will `cat` the *contents* of all the files and iterate over the lines of the result:

```
while read -r i
do
    echo "$i"
done < <(cat *.input)
```

If the files *contain* globbing characters, they won't be expanded. They keys are to not use `for` and to quote your variable.

In Bourne-derived shells that do not support process substitution, this is equivalent:

```
cat *.input | while read -r i
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The reason not to do that in Bash is that it creates a subshell and when the subshell (loop) exits, the values of variables set within and any `cd` directory changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have, a simple `cat *.input` will do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks & and sorry for not stating earlier, but the scrip is way too complicated dump here. `echo $i` is just a placeholder (`cat` in the for loop is also a complex combination of grep/sed/cut). If I can get this `echo` statement to print what is in the file literally, the rest will be solved.