# for loop includes wild characters (*.c) if no files with extension .c. How do I get around?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, for-loop

I am using bash on UNIX (sparc 10)

```
for file in $SCPATH/$LIBNAME/*.{gob,c,cpp,h};
do
    ln -s $file;
done;
```

The problem is: if there are no files with extension 'c', it will put "*.c" in $file and ln -s will create a link to '*.c'.
Is this a know issue? How can I get around it (besides the obvious 'if not *.c' hack).

Comment: See also [this relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111760/how-to-prevent-filename-expansion-in-for-loop-in-bash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to set nullglob before your loop

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

> **nullglob:**
>                         If set, bash allows patterns which match no files
>   (see Pathname Expansion above) to
>   expand to a null string, rather than
>   themselves.

When you're done and want to reset it to the original behavior, use:

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

As pointed out by Dennis Williamson in one of the comments.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot. How do I unset it?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know that too, really useful. Prior to knowing this, I've always used `[ $file != '*.c' ] || continue` inside the loop

Comment: @FYaqoob: `shopt -u nullglob`

Comment: If you don't need to transfer any variables from your loop to the outside, you could simply wrap it (including the `shopt` call) with parentheses: `(` ... `)`. Then the setting stays local inside.