# Avoiding expansion when looping: for x in $foo

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, wildcard, expansion

I have to count the number of executables in a directory.

I've already figured out a different way to do it (by writing to a file and then searching the file, but that is kind of ugly).

The solution that first came to me was this (the first argument is the directory path):

```
#!/bin/bash

noe=0

files=`ls -F $1` # because the -F option appends an indicator
                 # to the file, for an executable it's an '*'
                 # so if there is an executable 'script.sh' in the dir
                 # the output will be like this: 'script.sh*'

for i in $files
do
    if [ `echo "$i" | grep '*$'` ] #should search for an '*' at the end...
    then
        let noe += 1
    fi
done

echo $noe
```

This doesn't work because the '*' gets omitted in the for loop.

(the echo command in the for loop outputs a file-name without the '*' in the end, but works normally outside the for loop when the argument is in "")

There is a similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111760/how-to-prevent-filename-expansion-in-for-loop-in-bash), and I've managed to adapt the answer to my case, but it's not explained why it can't be done with for. + I don't fully understand why is there an additional `<` in the while loop

```
...
done < <(ls -F $1) 
     ^
     |_ I know that this means redirect to file to loop
        Does the second < mean that we are redirecting the
        standard input file? (this might be a stupid question)
```

The other question:
is there a way around this with the for loop and why?

Comment: The second `<` is part of the `<(command)` syntax for process substitution.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this should not under any circumstance [involve `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

You can iterate the files with a for-loop and use an `-x` test to determine if files are executable. However, directories are usually executable too (if they're not, you cannot enter them, e.g. with `cd`), so depending on whether you want to include directories in the result, you may need a `-d` test too. Example:

```
for file in ./*; do
    if [[ -x $file && ! -d $file ]]; then
        printf '<%s> is an executable file that is not a directory\n' "$file"
        (( count++ ))
    fi
done
printf '%d executable files found\n' "$count"
```

As for the second question:

> ```
> ...
> done < <(ls -F $1) 
>      ^
>      |_ I know that this means redirect to file to loop
>         Does the second < mean that we are redirecting the
>         standard input file? (this might be a stupid question)
> ```

`<(...)` is process substitution, and gets replaced by a filename to an fd or named pipe (depending on what the operating system supports). Any process that reads from this fd or named pipe, will get the output (stdout) of the command within `<(...)`

You can see this by using it with echo:

```
$ echo <(true)  # turns into  echo /dev/fd/63
/dev/fd/63
```

So in your case, `done < <(ls...)` turns into something like `done < /dev/fd/63`, which is the standard file redirection you're already familiar with.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for why using `ls` like this is a bad idea.

Comment: @EtanReisner, yes, that page can't be posted enough. I've added it to the first sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

Use find for finding files:

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$1" -type f -executable -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in $foo; do ...
```

...isn't looping over an array; it's looping over a **string**. Thus, to have the loop execute more than once, you **must** put the string through some kind of expansion, even if that expansion is nothing but string-splitting.

---

If you turned off all expansion, you would get this:

```
for x in "$foo"; do ...
```

...which will execute exactly once, making the loop useless.

---

Now, there's an intermediate position here: You can turn off glob expansion temporarily, but keep string splitting in place:

```
set -f              # disable all globbing
for x in $foo; do   # expand without globbing
  ...
done
set +f              # turn globbing back on
```

Note that the behavior of this won't necessarily be predictable unless you control the value of the variable `IFS`, which controls which characters string-splitting occurs on.

---

If you want to build an array, you can do that:

```
array=( "first element" "second element" "third element" )
for x in "${array[@]}"; do ...
```

...and in **that** case you can use `for` safely.